# Http Request POST doesn't work only if sent by Java App

Tags: java, wordpress, .htaccess, http-post

I have a my Wordpress site, installed by Bitnami in a AWS cloud server. Let's assume that the site is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)  .

I have also a Java application that sends http request (GET and POST) to my site, in order to exchange some infos (I use in Java: Apache HttpClient library ver. 4.5).

I implemented in the website the php code able to receive some specific http request, coming from my java app.
When the Java app sends an http request GET, it works.

The problem is with http request POST.
Let's consider for example the following http request POST:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/v1/meth-post?param=whatever
```

When I send that from my browser (I use a developper feature of FireFox) it works.

When I send exactly the same http request POST from my Java App I get the error message n. 301 from the website.
I saw googling this message means that the page was moved permantly.

Java code used to do the http request POST:

```
final StringEntity OGGETTO_StringEntity = new StringEntity(JSON_STRING, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
final HttpPost OGGETTO_HttpPost = new HttpPost("https://example.com/wp-json/v1/meth-post?param=whatever");
OGGETTO_HttpPost.setEntity(OGGETTO_StringEntity);
RESPONSE = OGGETTO_HttpClient.execute(OGGETTO_HttpPost);
```

Inside the .../wordpress/htdocs/.htaccess file I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I really cannot undertand why I have that error if the http request POST is exactly the same from browser and java app.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: this is probably cors problem. Could you edit the question with all headers that are part of 301 response.

Comment: @MihailoStupar that makes little sense, if it was, then why should they get a 301 response.

Comment: What are you actually sending? Your Java code appears to indicate that you are sending some JSON in the POST body, yet your description of the first request mentions nothing but a URL. So right now, we have nothing but your word for that these requests are supposedly "identical", but it really rather looks like they aren't actually.

Comment: Can you compare the headers for each case (java app vs browser ), could be a problem with the Authorization `RewriteRule` .. a missing header maybe?

Comment: Actually, I now think that it can be related to CSRF token. Why? It works from your browser, it means that you accessed the page (GET) and then from that page execute POST. Your browser collected CSRF token from GET and attached it to POST, so it works from there. On the other hand, from your java code you execute only POST request (without CSRF token). You can examine header from GET response and you should see CSRF token there.